# Why I am not able to access AWS IAM list, depsite having all IAM permission?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am getting following error, when I try to access IAM dashboard on aws.

```
User: arn:aws:iam::9490xxxxxxxx:user/xyz is not authorized to perform: iam:ListUsers on resource: arn:aws:iam::9490xsxxxxxxx:user/
```

The fact is that, I have `IAMFullPermission` policy attached to my account, as shown below :-[image]

I don't know, still what permissions I need to provide.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the policy is called `IAMFullPermission`? Because there is no AWS defined policy with that name. Is it possible this policy is custom one?

Comment: sorry, it's IAMFullAccess, as shown in the screenshot

Comment: I've tested the policy and it works fine for me. Can you test it by creating a dummy user and attach only that policy? I've a feeling one of the other policy might be blocking the policy from working.

Comment: One possible thing to try is to expand the IAMFullAccess and then you should see a simulate policy which you can click and try out to see if you have access to the ListUsers method using that policy

Answer (score 0):

As Rajesh commented, logging into the console and opening the policy simulator will allow you to select your user, and the iam:ListUsers permission and simulate the evaluation to find the exact reason for the failure.

> https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/home/index.jsp?#users

That screenshot of attached policies will give that user/role access to iam:ListUsers from multiple built in AWS polcies, and that error message suggests that the user does not have permission (i.e. a missing allow policy rather than an explicit deny).

When determining the cause of IAM errors I try the following:

1. Does the response appear cached? (Making changes to allow an action and then immediately attempting again does not always work. You can test this with the CLI by calling an API that will be not allowed. The first call will be slightly slower than subsequent calls. IAM changes can also take time to propagate).
2. What does the policy simulator say? (especially useful when considering more complicated policies with conditions like MFA required or MFA age)

The Policy Simulator will narrow down scenarios like:

1. User does not actually have that policy attached
2. User is part of a group that has an explicit deny policy (doesn't look to be the case here)
3. Other conditions are not satisfied that are not immediately apparent. E.g. MFA required or resource restrictions to only allow access to manage own user details.